# Pantone CMYK v. Solid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk, pantone, book

I am working in illustrator and creating a logo guidebook for a client.  When I go to choose my Pantone  color from the provided Pantone Color Book, it gives the option of Pantone CMYK and also Pantone Solid.

Is this referring to the process color printing versus spot color printing?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this referring to the process color printing versus spot color printing?

Yup! You got it exactly right there. The Pantone CMYK swatches are a set of Process swatches developed by Pantone. The Pantone Solids (Coated or Uncoated) are the Spot colours you are most likely looking for to design your brand book. You may also want to look at the Pantone Bridge swatches when converting your chosen Pantone Spot Colour to Process Colours.